# Are arrays covariant in their size?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, polymorphism

Is there a way to use the new `std::array` type polymorphically in the size of the array?  That is, if I have a function of the form

```
void DoSomething(std::array<int, 5>& myArray) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then is it *mathematically* well-defined to do the following (even if it's not legal C++ code?)

```
std::array<int, 10> arr;
DoSomething(arr);
```

Imof this is mathematically well-defined, is there a way to write `std::array` such that its array elements are contiguous and this code compiles?  The only technique I could think of would be to have some weird template metaprogram where `std::array<T, N+1>` inherits from `std::array<T, N>`, but I don't believe that forces the array elements to be contiguous.

Comment: Why not just templatize the function on `N` if you want compile-time polymorphism, or just use `std::vector` if you want runtime polymorphism?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel- Suppose that I want to have a function that always takes in an array of "at least five elements" or "at least ten elements."  I could do this with templates, but it would lead to gross code duplication and would require `static_assert`-esque code, which isn't elegant.  I can't check this statically with `std::vector`.  The idea of having the function take in an array of some size is thus an attempt to be like C99 statically-sized array parameters that can be checked at compile-time.

Comment: I'm not sure about your example.  Specifically, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "mathematically well-defined."  In `DoSomething`, if you query `std::distance(myArray.begin(), myArray.end())`, what do you expect the result to be?  `5` or `10`?

Comment: @James McNellis- I'm thinking "mathematically well-defined" means "array<5> is a subtype of array<3> in the mathematical sense of type theory."  I'd expect it to give 10, since that's the real length of the array.

Comment: @templatetypedef: if it gives 10, then it's not a array<T,5>. If DoSomething is meant to work on other size arrays, then it shouldn't be taking an array<T,5> specifically as an argument.  This is simple Liskov Substitution Principal stuff... not to be messed with.

Comment: @Tony- I like your line of reasoning, but there are other circumstances in which a derived class works differently from a base class, perhaps by overriding a base class method.  What separates the array case from this case?  Also, what about the case where the size would be 5 instead of 10?

Comment: @templatetypedef: template arguments exist for things known at compile time. If you want DoSomething to work on differently-sized `std::array` objects, simply use `template <size_t N> void DoSomething(Array<int, N>&);`. Otherwise, write DoSomething to accept N as a run-time argument. Many ways, including using an interfacing type holding reference and N or M (James' answer loses "M" but could easily save it), and providing a genuinely polymorphic accessor structure with a base class defining the interface (including size() member); array<> provides a function to decay to that RT mechanism.

Comment: @Tony- The idea is that I do know the sizes of all of the arrays at compile-time, but what I want is the ability to say "this takes in any array of size N or greater" (for some N) without the code bloat from multiple instantiations or the insecurity of delaying the test to runtime.

Comment: @templatetypedef: then an approach like James' is ideally suited to your needs... just snapshot M as an additional data member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly?  No.

You can, however, use compile-time polymorphism to achieve something very similar, and you can write a reference wrapper that makes it easier to work with in the code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ref_array_of_at_least
{
    template <std::size_t M>
    ref_array_of_at_least(T (&a)[M])
        : data_(a)
    {
        static_assert(M >= N, "Invalid size");
    }

    template <std::size_t M>
    ref_array_of_at_least(std::array<T, M>& a)
        : data_(&a[0])
    {
        static_assert(M >= N, "Invalid size");
    }

    T* data_;
};
```

Used as:

```
void f(ref_array_of_at_least<int, 5>) { }

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> x;
    std::array<int, 6> y;
    std::array<int, 4> z;
    f(x); // ok
    f(y); // ok
    f(z); // fail
}
```

(You'd need to add some `operator[]` overloads and such to `ref_array_of_at_least`, and it needs some work to make it const correct, but it's a start that demonstrates the possibility of what you are seeking.)

Answer (score 2):

If this was a requirement, one approach is a conversion operator to the required type:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
struct Array
{
    Array() { for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) x[i] = 0; }

    template <int N2>
    operator Array<T, N2>&()
    {
        // for safety, static assert that N2 < N...
        return reinterpret_cast<Array<T, N2>&>(*this);
    }

    int size() const { return N; }
    T x[N];

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array& a)
    {
        os << "[ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) os << a.x[i] << ' ';
        return os << ']';
    }
};


void f(Array<int, 5>& a)
{
    a.x[a.size() - 1] = -1;
}

int main()
{
    Array<int, 10> a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    f(a);
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it though: pretty horrid.  A more explicit mechanism seems a lot less prone to misuse, as well as being more powerful - something vaguely like:

```
template <size_t N2>
Array<T,N2>& slice(size_t first_index)
{
    return *(Array<T,N2>*)(data() + first_index);
}

// usage...
f(a.slice<5>(3));  // elements 3,4,5,6,7.
```

(clean up the casting for extra points :-/)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can fake it:

```
// Hide this function however you like: "detail" namespace, use "_detail"
// in the name, etc.; since it's not part of the public interface.
void f_detail(int size, int *data) {
  use(data, /* up to */ data + size);
}

int const f_min_len = 5;

template<int N>
void f(int (&data)[N]) {
  static_assert(N >= f_min_len);
  f_detail(N, data);
}

template<int N>
void f(std::array<int, N> &data) {
  static_assert(N >= f_min_len);
  f_detail(N, &data[0]);
}
```

This is a complete example, and should work exactly as presented.  You'd only have to change the data type from int (or make it a template parameter) and add const as required.